# Why does defaults only read from files with certain extended attributes?

Tags: macos, plist, defaults, extended-attributes

It seems that `defaults read` only works on property list files in certain folders (e.g. Desktop, Downloads) when the extended attribute `com.apple.macl` contains a specific value otherwise it reports that the key does not exist.

Create a `plist` file containing a key `foo` with the value `bar`.

```
$ echo '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>   <key>foo</key>
>   <string>bar</string>
> </dict>
> </plist>''' > ~/foobar.plist
```

Use `defaults read` to print the value of `foo`.

```
$ /usr/bin/defaults read ~/foobar.plist foo
bar
```

Copy the file from the home folder to the desktop.

```
$ cp ~/foobar.plist ~/Desktop
```

Trying to read the key with `defaults` there does not work, according to the error message because it does not exist.

```
$ /usr/bin/defaults read ~/Desktop/foobar.plist foo
2022-11-01 11:03:21.156 defaults[67556:1531405]
The domain/default pair of (/Users/stefan/Desktop/foobar.plist, foo) does not exist
```

`PlistBuddy` however reports correctly that key does in fact exist ( `plutil` also works fine).

```
$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print foo" ~/Desktop/foobar.plist
bar
```

The directory listing shows that the file on the desktop has an extended attribute.

```
$ ls -l ~/Desktop/foobar.plist
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 stefan  staff  228 Nov  1 11:03 /Users/stefan/Desktop/foobar.plist
```

The original file does not have an extended attribute.

```
$ ls -l ~/foobar.plist
-rw-rw-r--  1 stefan  staff  228 Nov  1 11:03 /Users/stefan/foobar.plist
```

The file on the desktop has the `com.apple.macl` attribute.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/Desktop/foobar.plist
com.apple.macl:
00000000  04 00 E7 04 31 F1 19 3B 41 2D BA 36 1D 05 19 2F  |....1..;A-.6.../|
00000010  D1 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          |........|
00000048
```

Copy the file from the desktop back to the home folder.

```
$ cp ~/Desktop/foobar.plist ~
```

The `com.apple.macl` attribute has been preserved on the copy.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/foobar.plist
com.apple.macl:
00000000  04 00 E7 04 31 F1 19 3B 41 2D BA 36 1D 05 19 2F  |....1..;A-.6.../|
00000010  D1 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          |........|
00000048
```

Reading the key from the file in the home directory works fine despite the presence of the `com.apple.macl` attribute.

```
$ /usr/bin/defaults read ~/foobar.plist foo
bar
```

Try to delete the `com.apple.macl` attribute from the file on the desktop.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -d com.apple.macl ~/Desktop/foobar.plist
```

The `com.apple.macl` attribute was not removed.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/Desktop/foobar.plist
com.apple.macl:
00000000  04 00 E7 04 31 F1 19 3B 41 2D BA 36 1D 05 19 2F  |....1..;A-.6.../|
00000010  D1 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          |........|
00000048
```

Try to delete the `com.apple.macl` attribute from the file in the home folder.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -d com.apple.macl ~/foobar.plist
```

The `com.apple.macl` attribute was removed.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/foobar.plist
```

In some way that I cannot remember I created another plist file that also had the `com.apple.macl` attribute but with a different value. The value of `com.apple.macl` starts with `04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1 FC BF` and the rest is zeros.

Write the alternative value of the `com.apple.macl` attribute to the file in the home folder.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -wx com.apple.macl '04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1 FC BF' ~/foobar.plist
```

The value of `com.apple.macl` was correctly written.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/foobar.plist
com.apple.macl:
00000000  04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1  |..[.{...I..4.[..|
00000010  FC BF                                            |..|
00000012
```

Copy the file from the home folder back to the desktop.

```
$ cp ~/foobar.plist ~/Desktop
```

The value written to the `com.apple.macl` attribute is still present, but has been extended with the value `04 00 E7 04 31 F1 19 3B 41 2D BA 36 1D 05 19 2F D1 0F` and zeros.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/Desktop/foobar.plist
com.apple.macl:
00000000  04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1  |..[.{...I..4.[..|
00000010  FC BF 04 00 E7 04 31 F1 19 3B 41 2D BA 36 1D 05  |......1..;A-.6..|
00000020  19 2F D1 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |./..............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          |........|
00000048
```

Reading the key from the file on the desktop now works.

```
$ /usr/bin/defaults read ~/Desktop/foobar.plist foo
bar
```

What is happening here?

Why does `defaults` seemingly only read a key from a property list file in the `Desktop` folder when the extended attribute `com.apple.macl` contains a specific value?

## Update

It seems when using `defaults write` to create the property list file the key is always found.

```
$ /usr/bin/defaults write ~/foobar.plist foo bar
$ /usr/bin/defaults read ~/foobar.plist foo
bar
$ /usr/bin/defaults write ~/Downloads/foobar.plist foo bar
$ /usr/bin/defaults read ~/Downloads/foobar.plist foo
bar
$ /usr/bin/defaults write ~/Documents/foobar.plist foo bar
$ /usr/bin/defaults read ~/Documents/foobar.plist foo
bar
$ /usr/bin/defaults write ~/Desktop/foobar.plist foo bar
$ /usr/bin/defaults read ~/Desktop/foobar.plist foo
bar
```

As above the extended attribute `com.apple.macl` is not present when the file is created in the home folder.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/foobar.plist
```

`com.apple.macl` gets assigned `04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1 FC BF` when the file is created in the `Documents` or `Downloads` folder.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/Documents/foobar.plist
com.apple.macl:
00000000  04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1  |..[.{...I..4.[..|
00000010  FC BF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          |........|
00000048

$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/Downloads/foobar.plist
com.apple.macl:
00000000  04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1  |..[.{...I..4.[..|
00000010  FC BF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          |........|
00000048
```

`com.apple.macl` gets assigned `04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1 FC BF 04 00 E7 04 31 F1 19 3B 41 2D BA 36 1D 05 19 2F D1 0F` when the file is created in the `Desktop` folder.

```
$ /usr/bin/xattr -l ~/Desktop/foobar.plist
com.apple.macl:
00000000  04 00 5B E7 7B 97 C0 D1 49 FF AD 34 CC 5B C3 B1  |..[.{...I..4.[..|
00000010  FC BF 04 00 E7 04 31 F1 19 3B 41 2D BA 36 1D 05  |......1..;A-.6..|
00000020  19 2F D1 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |./..............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          |........|
00000048
```

---

<sup>This was tested on macOS Catalina 10.15.7</sup>

Comment: The `com.apple.macl` extended attribute is part of the macOS privacy controls.